# P-Value from Sign Test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm so confused with this question and its answer provided as following:

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpgVF.png)

[The Answer provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIVo.png)

I totally don't understand why when we calculate the P-value, we need to calculate as $P(X \ge 1) = 1-P(X=0).$ Since we set the data less than 2 as positive sign here, then we only have 1 positive sign in the data set. Then what does $P(X=0)$ represent? And what does $P(X \ge 1)$ stand for?

Thank you for your help, I really can't get any answer directly from Google.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you are going to be a regular visitor to this site, you should learn to use MathJax to format your questions. Generally, it is not a good idea to link to problems or answers.

Answer (score 1):

> You have data $\{1,4,3,9,5\}$ from a symmetrical distribution with unknown
>   mean $\mu.$ You wish to find the P-value for a sign test of $H_0: \mu=2$ vs. $H_1: \mu < 2.$

To begin, only one of the five observations is smaller than 2, so there
hardly seems evidence that $\mu < 2.$ It seems that the person who decided
to test $H_0: \mu=2$ vs. $H_1: \mu < 2$ did not correctly anticipate the
nature of the population distribution.

Under $H_0$ the observed number $X$ of observations less than 2 has
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p=1/2).$ The P-value is the probability
of a more extreme result (in the direction of the alternative) than
what we have observed. If $H_1$ were true we would expect to see
more observations below 2.

So the P-value is
$$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X =0) = 1 - 1/32 = 31/32 = .96875.$$

> The linked answer gives the P-value as about 0.97.

Ordinarily, one does not expect to see such a large P-value. So I see why
this problem confused you. But the answer given is correct for the
(somewhat strangely posed) problem.

*Hote:* There is a saying among applied statisticians: If the P-value is very
small (say below 0.05), then doubt the null hypothesis; if the P-value is very
large (say above 0.95), then doubt the model. It is a way of saying
something may be wrong with assumptions or the statement of hypothesis and alternative, if you see such a large P-value.
If the alternative had been posed as $H_1: \mu > 2,$ then the P-value
would have been $1/32 = 0.0125 < 0.05$ and one would reject $H_O: \mu = 2.$

**Addendum:**  Here is a sign test in Minitab statistical software of
$H_0: \eta = 2$ vs $H_1: \eta < 2,$ were $\eta$ is the population *median.*
But for your symmetrical population the mean $\mu$ and the median are the same.

```
Sign Test for Median: X 

Sign test of median =  2.000 versus < 2.000

    N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
 X  5      1      0      4  0.9688   4.000
```